# Using sed on OSX bash script

Tags: bash, macos, sed, quoting

I am trying to replace all spaces in a csv file by commas.

The command

```
sed -i .bac ’s/\ /\,/g’ test.csv
```

does work in the OSX terminal, but not in the follwing script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
sed -i .bac ’s/\ /\,/g’ test.csv
sed ’s/\;//’ test.csv
i=0
while ((i<10))
do
((i=i+1))
sed -i .bac ’s/,,/,/g’ test.csv
done
rm *.bac
```

Terminal output:

```
./getEnergyLevels.sh
sed: 1: "’s/ /,/g’": invalid command code ? 
sed: 1: "’s/;//’": invalid command code ?
sed: 1: "’s/,,/,/g’": invalid command code ? 
sed: 1: "’s/,,/,/g’": invalid command code ? 
sed: 1: "’s/,,/,/g’": invalid command code ?
sed: 1: "’s/,,/,/g’": invalid command code ?
sed: 1: "’s/,,/,/g’": invalid command code ?
sed: 1: "’s/,,/,/g’": invalid command code ?
sed: 1: "’s/,,/,/g’": invalid command code ?
sed: 1: "’s/,,/,/g’": invalid command code ?
sed: 1: "’s/,,/,/g’": invalid command code ?
sed: 1: "’s/,,/,/g’": invalid command code ? 
./getEnergyLevels.sh:10: no matches found: *.bac
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: What is your input file? `Awk` is much more good at this, than `sed`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use normal apostrophes, i.e.,

```
sed -i .bac 's/\ /\,/g' test.csv
```

instead of the right single quotation mark (U+2019)

```
sed -i .bac ’s/\ /\,/g’ test.csv
```

Comment: Great that works, thx. I am writing the script in TextEdit. The ' is always replaced by a ’ after I edit a line. Kind of annoying. Any Idea how I can fix this? #edit seems to be the same char here in the comment: first ': apostroph second single "

Comment: @user7408924 deactivating "Text Replacement" and "Smart quotes" in the "Edit / Substitutions" menu might help...

Comment: Thx for the hint. Substitutions does not help, but Smart Quotes does :)

Comment: @user7408924 you got the answer to your specific question but why are you repeating the same sed command 10 times in a loop?

Comment: Also - there's no reason to escape spaces or commas, neither is a metacharacter.

Comment: @EdMorton I couldn't agree more, I just wanted to address why the particular sed command fails - without trying to advocate its existence ;)

Comment: @EdMorton Yes, the option "Smart Quotes" automatically changes the apostrophes to quotaions marks. I am repeating the same command to get rid of multiple commas but to always leave one left. I am using this script to edit an output of a programm that I want to import into excel.

Comment: My comment had nothing to do with quotes.

Comment: Ups yes, just ignore the first sentence of my previous comment ;)

Comment: Oh I see so you're addressing my question of why call sed 10 times in a loop. OK, got it. Don't do that. Post a new question with concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can show you how to really solve your problem.